# Lebesgue measure of set $M = \{ [x,y] \in \mathbb{R}^2; 2 < x + y < 3; x < y < 3x \}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

although we can do this by splitting the area four ways and computing four integrals, my book suggests that I try the substitution $ u = x + y$ and $ v = \frac{y}{x}$. 
I expressed $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$, what now?

Comment: Do we now have $2<u<3$, $1<v<3$? So the domain of integration is now a rectangle, or a product of intervals. But we should compute the appropriate Jacobian, no?

Comment: you mean the determinant of the Jacobian matrix? I got $\frac{u(1-v)}{(1+v)^3}$. Should I now integrate over the area?

Comment: By the way, we are doing something sort of like $\int dxdy=\int{\partial(x,y)\over\partial(u,v)}dudv$. I can't recall what the notation or technique is supposed to look like in the context of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Rather $u/(1+v)^2$. // Note that a simpler change of variables might be $u=x+y$, $v=x$, yielding the same measure $5/8$.

Comment: the answer is correct. I'm still working through the steps, though

Comment: Got it. $x = \frac{u}{v+1}, y = \frac{uv}{v+1}, \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} = \frac{1}{v+1}, \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} = \frac{-u}{(v+1)^2}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = \frac{v}{v+1}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} = \frac{u}{(v+1)^2} $. This yields the determinant $\frac{u}{(v+1)^2} $

Comment: Ah, I had it wrong, my mistake. Deleting the misleading comments.